# Proof of Stake leader-election

Tags: proof-of-stake, consensus, validators, block-production

So I understand Proof-of-work high level, where nodes work to solve a "puzzle". And once they've created a valid block they then broadcast it to the network. So that node receives the reward (assuming valid).

But in Proof-of-stake, the winner is selected by how much it has staked. So lets say there are 10 validators, and each one has 32 Eth staked. Who chooses who the block creator is? Or if each validator creates their own block and proposes it, who chooses which one to accept?